# curious dependency loading behaviour in requirejs

Tags: requirejs

I've been having trouble loading dependencies in requirejs, so have tried to recreate the simplest possible structure that shows my problem. The html file contains a bootstrap typeahead box that I want to fill with data once the page loads. If my main.js script is:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
    bootstrap: 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-optamd3-min',
    cs: 'libs/require/cs',
    'coffee-script': 'libs/coffeescript/coffee-script'
  },
  shim: {
    bootstrap: {
      deps: ['jquery']
  }
});

require(['cs!router']);
```

and my backbone entry point is a very simple router:

```
define ['jquery','underscore','backbone','bootstrap'], ($, _, Backbone) ->

  AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend

    initialize: () ->
      @data = ['one','two','three']

    routes: '': 'index'

    index: () ->
      $('.typeahead').typeahead({source:@data})

  app_router = new AppRouter
  Backbone.history.start()
```

then if the page loads from a cleaned webcache, I get the following errors on the console:

TypeError: a is not a function

TypeError: $(".typeahead").typeahead is not a function

Error: Load timeout for modules: cs!router 
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout

If I simply reload the page, all the errors disappear and everything works ok. I'd be really grateful if someone could explain to me what is happening here, thanks.

Comment: I believe the `define` in your main script should be a `require`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that require(['cs!app']); is after the config stuff, and my main app script begins: define ['jquery',...,'bootstrap'] ...

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but you don't need the `exports: 'bootstrap'`. See: http://blog.credera.com/topic/technology-solutions/java/modular-javascript-with-requirejs/

Comment: didn't affect the main issue... am re-editing the post to make my structure clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed by using

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require-jquery.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
```

in main html file.